# How do i add all android icons to my app

Tags: android, icons, drawable

I found the drawable folder in my android/sdk folder but I am unsure where to copy the folder to in my project. I have a debug folder with some icons but copying the drawable folder from the android/sdk to my debug folder doesn't do anything. I would like to be able to type R.drawables. but all I get in my code when I type R.drawable. is a list of abc_ icons. see picture. I want to copy the entire  android 21 drawable folder or whatever i need to copy out of the android 21 folder to add the icons to my project.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What you wanna copy?

Comment: i added a picture to question of exactly where i am trying to get the icons from that i want to add to my project

Comment: Do you want to add images to be used in the project or what ?

Comment: I think those are official theme has been already added to your project

Comment: if i put R.drawable. nothing but the abc_ items come up for selection.

Answer (score 1):

just copy past those .png icons to your project drawables and rename with related name and remove the special(_a_holo) etc characters in those .png which copied into your project. example do: abcholo.png give like this.

Comment: where is my project drawables folder?I have copied images in lots of places but cant seem to find where the place people are calling drawables. Also I have no folder in my project with the name drawables.

Comment: i found drawable-hdpi,drawable-mdpi,drawable-xhdpi,and drawable-xxhdpi in my project under app-> source -> main -> res. I added the image to each of those folders for testing and in my project in android studio a folder appeared under res -> drawable. after that I was able to use R.drawable.myImage. If anyone else uses this method make sure you go and properly resize the image for the sizes in each one of the drawable folder.

Answer (score 1):

Copy your image in the drawable folder of your project, not in the android sdk drawable folder.
You can use the images in XML by using `<ImageView ... src="@drawable/yourimageview" />`

Answer (score 0):

hi if u don't find the drawables create drawables in your project under the res folder and use the to that drawables you copy all your icons and use user icons.